# Changing the font size of the PanoramaItem (windows phone)

Tags: windows-phone-7, font-size, panorama-control

I am trying to change the size of the PanoramaItem's title, but it doesnt work. I tried the FontSize attribute, but it does nothing. I could change the font size of the Panorama's title using this code:

```
        <controls:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" FontSize="100" Margin="0,50,0,0" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting `Panorama.HeaderTemplate` instead of `TitleTemplate`

It usually helps to open controls in Expression Blend when trying to style them for the first time, It makes it very easy to see all the different templates involved and their default values.